# How to find all fixed points of $x^3-x^2-4x+5$?

Tags: fixed-points

How to find all fixed points of $x^3-x^2-4x+5$ if has exactly 3 and $x=1$ is one of them?

I found this problem, and normally one has a reduced domain and range say $[a,b]$ to $[a,b]$ then if it's Lipschitz ($\lambda <1$) for example there is only one fixed point.... However if I already have one, how to find the other two? Is there a theorem or procedure?

Comment: You have a cubic equation and you know one of the roots. Factor that out and your are left with a quadratic.

Comment: Well if you identify the correct cubic, you have a root and can reduce it to a quadratic ...

Comment: By definition, a fixed point $x^*$ of a function $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x^*) = x^*$.

Comment: In fact it isn't hard to just see that the other two fixed points are $\pm\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @Servaes oh thank you, by definition it's clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed points are the solutions to the cubic
$$x^3-x^2-5x+5=0.$$
You are given the solution $x=1$, so you can factor out the factor $x-1$, leaving a quadratic, which you surely know how to solve.